# How can I resolve the issue of remote config pulling at different times in the APK compared to the Play Store version?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, firebase-remote-config

I have a unity mobile app in which I make a request to get the data from the server

```
async private Task<ConfigDataModel> GetConfigDataAsync(string userPublicId)
{
    return await RequestManager.Instance.GetConfigDataAsync(userPublicId);
}
```

And in parallel I init the remote config to pull the data from there.

```
public void Init(Dictionary<string, object> defaults, UserMainProperties userMainProperties, int fetchTimeout)
        {
            this.defaults = defaults;
            FirebaseCoreService.Instance.Init(async() =>
            {
                await InitializeRemoteConfig(fetchTimeout);
            },
            () =>
            {
                InitEnded = true;
                onRemoteConfigFetchFail?.Invoke();
            });
        }
```

The issue I have is the following

When I build the app locally and install the .apk file on my android device and run the app, pulling the data from remote config takes twice and more longer than when I install the same app from Play Store

Here is some statistics of request duration vs remote config pull duration in seconds

```
apk             
config data     3 3.8 2.6 3.1
remote config   7.2 6.8 4.2 6.1

play store              
config data     2.7 2.6 2.5 2.6
remote config   1.7 0.5 0.7 0.8
```

As you can see remote config fetch takes much longer in case of .apk

Is there any idea why remote config takes so long when the app installed via the .apk?

I have some doubts that during the installation from the play store Google play services detects that remote config data needs to be fetched and it starts the fetching much earlier than in case of .apk, but I couldn't find anything about this in the docs.

Note that I install the both versions of the app on the same device, and use the same wifi connection.

Comment: How are you measuring this?  There should be enough information in the question that someone could use perform the same benchmarks and observe the same results.

Comment: Well, in order to measure the same benchmarks you need to have a firebase remote config account, register an application there, integrate the unity SDK in your unity app. It is not possible to include everything in the question. My goal is to understand if someone else met something similar and/or might know the reason.

Comment: May it have something to do with the fact that the app from Play Store is automatically linked with user's Google Play Service, while manually installed APK is not? Tht's just a pure assumption, but maybe...

Comment: @Xander, I also think so, but couldn't find any docs about that.